# java runtime.exec with redirection character (Not for redirection)

Tags: java, redirect, runtime, operator-keyword

Now I'm working on the command, Mafft.

This command's usage is like below.

**mafft in > out**

as you can see, command line contains redirection operator.

This command line on windows os, it works.
This command line on linux shell prompt input directly, it works.

But if I run it through java Runtime().getRuntime().exec("command string", null), 
it gives me nothing but errors below.

Unknown option:  /home/test/msa.txt
Unknown option:  >

Is there any way to use redirection operator in command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirection with Runtime.getRuntime().exec() doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130787/redirection-with-runtime-getruntime-exec-doesnt-work)

Comment: No, that is about to make redirection work. But my case is about using redirection character only. I don't need redirection.